# PHP form processing

Tags: php, jquery

I realise this may be a Noob question but I have read over 40 posts and am still none the wiser as to where or possibly even how to sanitize the output from the form I attach.

I found the following code (I have adapted it to fit my form). I have seen on here so many different ways of Sanitizing input that I am now thoroughly confused. Is the following actually sanitizing or not? The javascript in the html part doesn't seem to be validating either.
 First is the html part, I have stripped out all the bits I completely understand but apologies for the length of it:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(form) {
        fail  = validateContactname(form.Contactname.value)
        fail += validateTelephonenumber(form.Telephonenumber.value)
        fail += validateEmailaddress(form.Emailaddress.value)
        fail += validateBoxwidtha(form.Boxwidtha.value)
        fail += validateBoxdepthb(form.Boxdepthb.value)
        fail += validateBoxheightc(form.Boxheightc.value)
        fail += validateContents(form.Contents.value)
        fail += validatePrinting(form.Printing.value)
        fail += validateFinishing(form.Finishing.value)
        fail += validateBoxquantity1(form.Boxquantity1.value)
        fail += validateBoxquantity2(form.Boxquantity2.value)
        fail += validateBoxquantity3(form.Boxquantity3.value)
        fail += validateBoxquantity4(form.Boxquantity4.value)
        if (fail == "") return true
        else { alert(fail); return false }
    }
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>

<form method="post" action="test_rb.php" onSubmit="return validate(this)">

  <div id="contact-form">

      <div class="contact-form-sections">  <!-- Start of contact details section -->
          <div class="contact-form-sections-headings">  
            Please supply your contact details</div>
      <br />
         Your Contact Name (required)  <br />      
         <input name="Contactname" type="text" size="30" maxlength="35" required/><br /><br />

         Your Telephone number (required)   <br />        
         <input name="Telephonenumber" type="text" maxlength="15" required/><br /><br />

         Your e-mail address  (required) <br />         
         <input name="Emailaddress" type="text" size="30" maxlength="55" required/><br /><br />


       </div>

        </div><!--end of container/wrapper div -->
    <script>
function validateContactname(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Contactname was entered.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateTelephonenumber(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Telephone was entered.\\n"
    else if (field.length < 5)
        return "Telephone Numbers must be at least 10 numbers long.\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Only numbers allowed in Telephones Numbers.\n"
    return ""
}

function validateEmailaddress(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Email Address was entered.\\n"
        else if (!((field.indexOf(".") > 0) &&
                 (field.indexOf("@") > 0)) ||
                /[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field))
        return "The Email address is invalid.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxwidtha(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Box Width was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box width should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxdepthb(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Box Width was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box depth should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxheightc(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Box Height was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box Height should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

<!-- No text is required in the Contents field -->
<!-- No text is required in the Printing field -->
<!-- No text is required in the Finishing field -->

function validateBoxquantity1(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Quantity was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box Height should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxquantity2(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Quantity was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box Quantity should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxquantity3(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Quantity was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box Quantity should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}

function validateBoxquantity4(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No Quantity was entered.\\n"
    else if (/[^0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Box Quantity should only contain numbers.\\n"
    return ""
}
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

The following PHP works but doesn't seem to Sanitize. Also I can't seem to add anymore error checking as it then falls over.

```
<?php 
 $to = 'someone@hotmail.co.uk' ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress'] ; 
 $contactname = $_REQUEST['Contactname'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Box Quote Request";


 // Checks to see if anything has been typed into the form
// and calls the fix_string function to sanitize the input
if (isset($_POST['Contactname']))
    $Contactname = fix_string($_POST['Contactname']);
if (isset($_POST['Telephonenumber']))
    $Telephonenumber = fix_string($_POST['Telephonenumber']);
if (isset($_POST['Emailaddress']))
    $Emailaddress = fix_string($_POST['Emailaddress']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxwidtha']))
    $Boxwidtha = fix_string($_POST['Boxwidtha']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxdepthb']))
    $Boxdepthb = fix_string($_POST['Boxdepthb']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxheightc']))
    $Boxheightc = fix_string($_POST['Boxheightc']);
if (isset($_POST['Contents']))
    $Contents = fix_string($_POST['Contents']);
if (isset($_POST['Printing']))
    $Printing = fix_string($_POST['Printing']);
if (isset($_POST['Finishing']))
    $Finishing = fix_string($_POST['Finishing']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxquantity1']))
    $Boxquantity1 = fix_string($_POST['Boxquantity1']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxquantity2']))
    $Boxquantity2 = fix_string($_POST['Boxquantity2']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxquantity3']))
    $Boxquantity3 = fix_string($_POST['Boxquantity3']);
if (isset($_POST['Boxquantity4']))
    $Boxquantity4 = fix_string($_POST['Boxquantity4']);



 //this bit sets the sections of the form and must have an entry for each form element
 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Contactname"} = "Contact Name"; 
 $fields{"Telephonenumber"} = "Telephone Number"; 
 $fields{"Emailaddress"} = "Email Address"; 
 $fields{"Boxwidtha"} = "Box width or a"; 
 $fields{"Boxdepthb"} = "Box depth or b"; 
 $fields{"Boxheightc"} = "Box height or c"; 
 $fields{"Contents"} = "Contents"; 
 $fields{"Printing"} = "Printing"; 
 $fields{"Finishing"} = "Finishing"; 
 $fields{"Boxquantity1"} = "Box Quantity 1"; 
 $fields{"Boxquantity2"} = "Box Quantity 2"; 
 $fields{"Boxquantity3"} = "Box Quantity 3"; 
 $fields{"Boxquantity4"} = "Box Quantity 4"; 

 //this bit prints out each fields title and contents in turn each on new line
 $body = "A quote request:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){  $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 //this bit is the stuff that goes to the enquirer
 $headers2 = "From: raymond@redborneprinters.co.uk"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.website.co.uk/index";

 //this bit is what shows if there is an error
 if($from == '') {print "We need an email address to be able to contact you, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($contactname == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 

 //this bit is used if there are no errors
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: http://www.website.co.uk/thank-you-for-quote.html" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify email@address.co.uk"; } 


 }
}

 function fix_string($string) 
 {
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlentities($string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    return $string
}


 ?>
```

All help gratefully received, I have spent over a week trying to get this to work and am still going round in circles.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "sanitizing"?

Comment: Sanitize for WHAT target environment? This isn't something like a shotgun blast - blast an area with pellets and hope you hit something. sanitization/escaping is something that should be TARGETTED for a specific usage

Comment: Hi @FastTrack - I had hoped that the function fix_string would be called and that that would do some cleaning up and prevent at least some attempts at sending spam through the site when it goes live. I realise from reading so much on here that this is a vast subject and that as a newcomer to PHP I am only going to be able to do the simplest of things at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at filters, http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php

here is an example from the link. It test for emails.

```
$a = 'joe@example.org';

$sanitized_a = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (filter_var($sanitized_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (a) sanitized email address is considered valid.\n";
}
```